# Android - Cloud Save doesn't work

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, byte, google-cloud-storage

i've implement Cloud Save in my app. The sample works fine (with my package and key SHA, the same of the Console). So, i modified the sample code with this..i have two buttons

**Upload**  : `save to cloud`

```
    void saveToCloud() {  

    //public int cLUN1 = 3; kl1 is the int stateKey (slot) ; bLUN1 the byte
    byte[] bLUN1 = String.valueOf(cLUN1).getBytes();
    getAppStateClient().updateStateImmediate(this, kl1, bLUN1);
```

**Download**  : `download from cloud`

```
    void saveToDevice() { 

    //mint1 is the textview ; kl1 the slot to restore 
    getAppStateClient().loadState(this, kl1);
    mint1.setText(" "+kl1);
```

From my device i receive **always 0** as text of TextView mint1. Why  i not get the correct variable?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

```
    void saveToCloud() {

    bLUN1 = String.valueOf(cLUN1).getBytes();
    bLUN2 = String.valueOf(cLUN2).getBytes();

    getAppStateClient().updateStateImmediate(this, key1, bLUN1);
    getAppStateClient().updateStateImmediate(this, key2, bLUN2);
    }


     void loadFromCloud() {

     mLoadingDialog.show();
     getAppStateClient().loadState(this, key1);
     getAppStateClient().loadState(this, key2);
    }
```

I also edited `onStateLoaded`

```
   @Override
    public void onStateLoaded(int statusCode, int stateKey, byte[] localData) {
        mLoadingDialog.dismiss();
        switch (statusCode) {

        case AppStateClient.STATUS_OK:
            mAlreadyLoadedState = true;
            hideAlertBar();

            mint1.setText(new String(bLUN1, charset));
            mint2.setText(new String(bLUN2, charset));

            break;
          ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kl1 is the slot id, not the saved data.  Your `onStateLoaded` and `onStateConflict` methods will be called with the saved data value.